# Espresso typeText() vs editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(null, false, true));

Tags: android, android-view, android-espresso

To help EditText reject keystrokes that are not a valid number, you set a DigitsKeyListener like this:

`myEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(null, false, true));`

That works under manual test - you can type `42..`, and the keystroke for the second dot goes away like it never happened. If we are helping the user type floating point numbers this is great, because we don't need to wait until they submit the form and then set an error.

But I can't TDD the DigitsKeyListener, because in Espresso this works:

`onView(withId(R.id.my_edit_text)).perform(typeText("42.."));`

The second `.` goes into the field, so I can't then assert that the KeyListener rejected it!

(I can TDD that the KeyListener is *set*, but that's programming to the artifact and not to the feature.)

What is the point of `typeText()`, which seems to work at the raw keystroke input level, if it bypasses KeyListeners? Sending each key individually also did not get filtered:

`onView(withId(R.id.my_edit_text)).perform(typeText("4"));`
`onView(withId(R.id.my_edit_text)).perform(typeText("2"));`
`onView(withId(R.id.my_edit_text)).perform(typeText("."));`
`onView(withId(R.id.my_edit_text)).perform(typeText("."));`